# Rotating a Vector2 around a point

Tags: math, vector, three.js, geometry

I'm trying to understand what happens when we rotate a Vector around an arbitrary point. If p.x was 0 then the angle would be 90 and I understand that, but I can't visualize why it is 45 when I use p.x = 50.

```js
var v = new THREE.Vector2(100,0);
var p = new THREE.Vector2(50,0);

v.rotateAround(p, 90 * Math.PI/180);
console.log('Angle: ', v.angle() * 180/Math.PI);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r82/three.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are rotating the point `v` around the point `p`. This is done by rotating the vector `v-p` around the origin and adding the resulting vector (read point translation) back to `p`.

As `v-p=(50,0)` the 90° rotation gives `(0,50)` and adding back `p`gives the point `(50,50)` which is at angle 45° relative to the origin, but still straight up from `p`.

```
  |           v after rotation
  |         o
  |         .
  |         .
  |         .
  |         .
--o---------+---------o-----
origin      p         v at start
```

Comment: I know i'm pushing this a little, but any chance of a visual to aid my understanding?

Comment: Added a cheap ASCII sketch.